# Looking for a working example to use a custom ConsumerAwareRebalanceListener in Spring Kafka 2.1.0

Tags: spring-kafka

According to the docs:

> ContainerProperties has a property consumerRebalanceListener which
>   takes an implementation of the Kafka client’s
>   ConsumerRebalanceListener interface. If this property is not provided,
>   the container will configure a simple logging listener that logs
>   rebalance events under the INFO level. The framework also adds a
>   sub-interface ConsumerAwareRebalanceListener [...]

However there doesn't seem to be an injection point or a lifecycle phase to actually assign custom rebalance listeners to `ContainerProperties`.

In my case I am using auto-configuration and the beans are primarily provided by `KafkaAnnotationDrivenConfiguration` and `KafkaAutoConfiguration`.

Unlike many Spring classes and components, there's no way to set a custom rebalance listener by defining a bean of a certain type, and the only option seems to be hacking and subclassing existing beans.

Or is there something that I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

There is `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer` you need to extend, call `super.configure()` and use:

```
ContainerProperties containerProperties = listenerContainerFactory
            .getContainerProperties();
```

To get access to the container properties for the `@KafkaListener` . And already there you can inject your `RebalanceListener`.

And right: that custom `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer` must be declared as a `@Bean`:

```
@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer kafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer(
        ConsumerAwareRebalanceListener rebalanceListener) {

    return new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer() {

        @Override
        public void configure(ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> listenerContainerFactory,
                ConsumerFactory<Object, Object> consumerFactory) {
            super.configure(listenerContainerFactory, consumerFactory);
            listenerContainerFactory.getContainerProperties()
                    .setConsumerRebalanceListener(rebalanceListener);
        }

    };

}
```

Exactly this bean is used from the `KafkaAnnotationDrivenConfiguration` to build `kafkaListenerContainerFactory` bean:

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(name = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer,
        ConsumerFactory<Object, Object> kafkaConsumerFactory) {
```

Comment: Perhaps add a new feature request against Spring Boot to auto detect if there's a single CRB bean in the context.

Comment: I think something like `interface KafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer` should be enough to let end-users to populated such a bean (`return listenerContainerFactory -> ...`) and delegate to it from the `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer` if it exists in the application context.

Comment: They like to call them `...Customizers` now - I have an open PR for customizing the `RetryTemplate` [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/pull/11697).